# Declaring an array of function pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, header-files

I am working on a project with a .h file and a .cpp file.  I'm writing a function that I want to take advantage of an array of function pointers, where each function in the array is called based on a condition related to an enum.  I have declared the 5 functions and the array itself in my .h file.  In which file should I set each value of the array equal to the appropriate function (.h or .cpp)?

Comment: Only put in the H file what is required outside the cpp file. Should any other entity ever have access to that information? if yes, .h if no, .cpp. With such a simple project it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Really a matter of taste. I would initialize the array in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

I predict you'd have issues if the array definition itself is in the .h file.

You should **define** the array (along with the setting of values) in your .c file.

And in the .h file **declare** the array as an extern, like so:

```
extern func_pointer_t array[];
```

But globals are a bad idea in general, you should consider supplying an API for getting a function pointer out of the array.

```
func_pointer_t get(unsigned int i);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, variable assignments take place in the ".cpp" file.  If you need it global, you would put something in a .h file.

Also, be aware that only one function pointer type can exist in an array.  In other words, all the functions must have the same signature.

If you change the array to hold a function object, or a pointer to a function object, you could have many varieties of function objects that derive from a base function object.

See also `std::vector` and `std::map`.

Comment: +1 just curious, can you have a pointer to a function pointer? and if so your array could store those, no?

Comment: @AK4749: As with integers, a pointer to an integer pointer is another indirection to the *same* data type.  Each *function signature* is treated as a distinct type for function pointers.  So, a pointer to a function pointer won't help people who need a pointer to *any* function.